# Internet is back check signal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

My app loads up stuff into a database, so I need an Internet connection.

I thought, if I have no network connection, I could store the data on my device and upload it later.

So my question is, how can I check if the connection is back? Is there a signal I can catch with a handler which uploads it later, or do have I to check every 5 seconds?

I am using Cordova with AngularJs!

Comment: The way I have my AJAX work is to check if a request fails due to a network error (usually you get a failure with error code `0`, IE likes to send error codes greater than `999`), and then retry a few seconds later. Repeat until eventually the net will return and the request succeeds. You can vary this pattern to save the request for later, eg. "right, it's been about an hour, let's see if the net's up". Basically, just retry and check for network failure.

Comment: Sounds good, but is there no passiv way, like a signal I can catch?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. "Try and see" is probably the best option.

Comment: [Some browsers have online/offline events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events) In a cordova app you likely have other device connection api's available also. (is beyond my knowledge area)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [network plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-network-information). It defines an online and an offline event, that trigger when you get an internet connection or loose it...

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
 function onOffline() {
 alert('Check your internet connection and try again);
}
```